# List the number of files after a specific file format search

Tags: linux, terminal

I am in a directory when it contains tons of folders.
And as I am searching for a specific file format, I was wondering, can I add on any more commands to the search command I used to specify the number of items?

Cause what I am seeing are a tons of files in different folders and it is a huge list

The search command I am using is:

```
find -name "*.xml"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see only first 10 resulting lines, you can use

```
find -name '*.xml' | head -n10
```

To see the last 12, use

```
find -name '*.xml' | tail -n12
```

There is also a pager.

```
find -name '*.xml' | less
```

To get the number of files, use `wc` (`-l` counts lines):

```
find -name '*.xml' | wc -l
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I do not think they are what I am looking for. I had much wanted to know the overall number of items that has `.xml`

Comment: Thanks. That is definitely what I am looking for. Could I trouble you to tell me what does `| wc -1` means? Like is there a technical term for it, I am asking as I am unable to garner any results in the web

Comment: @user3212246: `|` is called a "pipe". You connect the output of the left hand command to the input of the right hand one. `wc` counts words, characters or lines.

Comment: Just one last question. Using the given command you have stated, for example if it has tabulated a total of 12 files.. Is there any ways possible to look thru the contents of the 12 files and filter those containing a certain keyword?

Comment: So can I take it I can integrate along with your code as well?

Comment: @user3212246: if you know how, you can :-)